# Camera2 how to detect focus on a metering area

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, autofocus, exposure

Afternoon,

I have an application that detects something in the scene. This runs on live camera preview. I now want to use the results of a (successful) detection to set certain points of interest for exposure and focus in the image.

I have implemented iOS based on [FocusPointOfInterest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1385853-focuspointofinterest) and [ExposurePointOfInterest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1388777-exposurepointofinterest) (works fine). In Android i am using [MeteringRectangle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/MeteringRectangle) to set the [ControlAfRegions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_AF_REGIONS) and [ControlAeRegions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#CONTROL_AE_REGIONS) on a repeating capture request.

In iOS the autofocus is triggered automatically when the FocusPointOfInterest mentioned above loses focus on that area.

In Android the exposure reacts to different points (that change dynamically) but the focus doesn't.
This also happens even in the simple case where one single area is defined for focus/exposure upon setup of the camera preview. In this case, I get exposure to react ok to the area defined but focus never changes even if the area loses focus. My understanding is that the focus metering area would drive new autofocus triggers if the area lost focus/changed significantly.

**Tried**

- Everytime a an area changes due to detection i call *SetUpCaptureRequestMeteringAreas* and *TriggerAutoFocus* but, because the area can change a lot due to a dynamic detection then the auto focus trigger enters an "infinite" loop
- Listen to the state of AF in the [capture callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback) but after the first initial autofocus trigger the camera AF state goes from inactive->active scan->focus locked (which should be) but it just stays in focus locked no matter if the focus region is in focus or not
- Tried setting continuous picture for focus mode and still setting the focus metering area. The autofocus triggers sometimes but unfortunately this seems like based on the whole scene and ignores the metering area set.
- There is an interesting [property](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#CONTROL_AF_SCENE_CHANGE_DETECTED) that could be related but i couldn't manage any device that i possess to recognise this property or the [capture control](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult#CONTROL_AF_SCENE_CHANGE) (control_af_scene_change) associated with it.

Apologies, code is Xamarin/.NET and not native but should be self explanatory.

**Camera setup code**

```
...
SetUpCaptureRequestBuilder(mPreviewRequestBuilder);
mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.Build();
mPreviewSession.SetRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);

SetUpCaptureRequestMeteringAreas(new PointF(0.1f, 0.5f), new PointF(0.9f, 0.5f));
TriggerAutoFocus(null);
...
```

```
public void SetUpCaptureRequestMeteringAreas(PointF focusPt, PointF exposurePt)
{
    Rect sensorSize = (Rect)mCharacteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.SensorInfoActiveArraySize);

    // Create MeteringRectangle for focus
    MeteringRectangle focusAreaTouch = new MeteringRectangle(
                (int)(focusPt.X * sensorSize.Width()),
                (int)(focusPt.Y * sensorSize.Height()),
                (int)(sensorSize.Width() * 0.02),
                (int)(sensorSize.Height() * 0.02),
                MeteringRectangle.MeteringWeightMax);
    MeteringRectangle[] focusRegions = new MeteringRectangle[] { focusAreaTouch };

    // Create MeteringRectangle for exposure
    MeteringRectangle exposureAreaTouch = new MeteringRectangle(
                (int)(exposurePt.X * sensorSize.Width()),
                (int)(exposurePt.Y * sensorSize.Height()),
                (int)(sensorSize.Width() * 0.02),
                (int)(sensorSize.Height() * 0.02),
                MeteringRectangle.MeteringWeightMax);
    MeteringRectangle[] exposureRegions = new MeteringRectangle[] { exposureAreaTouch };

    // TODO check if supported first
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAfRegions, focusRegions);
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAeRegions, exposureRegions);
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAwbRegions, exposureRegions);
    mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.Build();
    try
    {
        mPreviewSession.SetRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, null, mBackgroundHandler);
    }
    catch (CameraAccessException ex)
    {
        ex.PrintStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
public void TriggerAutoFocus(CameraCaptureListener captureCallback)
{
    // autofocus trigger need to be submited in a single capture request
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAfMode, new Java.Lang.Integer((int)ControlAFMode.Auto));
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.Set(CaptureRequest.ControlAfTrigger, new Java.Lang.Integer((int)ControlAFTrigger.Start));
    mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.Build();
    
    try
    {
        mPreviewSession.Capture(mPreviewRequest, mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
    }
    catch (CameraAccessException ex)
    {
        ex.PrintStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: ControlAfTrigger does a full new scan and locks the lens, so probably using a continuous focus mode and updating the regions is the most suitable when regions are being updated very fast. This seems to be the 3rd point you tried, are you triggering AF in this case? That'd lock the AF so you should not be triggering AF.

Comment: Also see the following page if you haven't already. 
 https://source.android.com/docs/core/camera/camera3_3Amodes

Comment: Also note that all devices may not support continuous AF mode. You can use [ControlAfAvailableModes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#CONTROL_AF_AVAILABLE_MODES) to check if a device supports it. For debugging purpose, you can trying using the [watch command](https://source.android.com/docs/core/camera/debugging#start) to see if the requests are being submitted and received properly and what the camera is doing. You can use something like `adb shell cmd media.camera watch start -m 3a && adb shell cmd media.camera watch live` and then test.

Comment: Thanks @TahsinMasrur. Yes that is what i tried. What I didn't try in that was to set continuous again after the point changes so i'll revisit that attempt. However i've observed that the continuous mode sets the focus based on the whole scene rather than the point so i'm not sure if that will work. Perhaps my observation comes from the fact that i set the continuous focus mode first and only then the point? perhaps setting the focus point needs to happen first and only then continuous mode should be set. something to explore. unfortunately the docs do not specify that.

Comment: It should be ok to set the AF mode first and then set the focus points. Besides, you focus point will change later anyway.

Comment: But you do need to set the AF mode (and any other required parameter as well) in all the capture requests you set, otherwise, it will be replaced by the one in template as default.